# Can c# auto correct syntax casing like VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there a setting that will allow C# to auto correct it's casing similar to VB.NET.  For example when I type `dim x as integer` in VB.NET, it automatically converts it to `Dim x As Integer`, but c# does not do this type of stuff.

Comment: No. Variables are case sensitive in C#, so it can't correct the casing for you.

Comment: The language is case-sensitive, but typically the Visual Studio IDE is able to help you with that via intelli-sense

Comment: @Xaisoft: Doesn't matter. You can have a variable named "Public" if you want, even though "public" is a keyword. So how can it tell the difference? (note: I said you can, I didn't say it was a good idea!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, because C# is case sensitive. The two statements could have completely different meanings. There'd be no way for the IDE to know which you meant to use.

Comment: If I do something like FOREACH ..., shouldn't c# auto correct that to foreach or am I missing something here?

Comment: Technically it's not the language doing anything, the IDE is doing the correcting for you based on the language's standards.  Since C# is case sensitive and what I like to call "normal", it does not provide this functionality by default (a 3rd party IDE extension may offer this feature).

Comment: -1 @Justin there is always a way.  In this case it wouldn't be that hard.  If autocorrect casing were to be enabled as a feature in VS for C# all the IDE would have to do is enforce all variable names were unique...a pretty simple compiler modification would help to do the trick...

Answer (score 1):

There is something that visual studio will offer you.

Let's say you want a `DateTime`, but you typed `datetime`.  After you finish typing (and assuming you have the correct usings/imports specified) you can press CTRL+Spacebar, and visual studio will try to correct it (or suggest alternatives) using IntelliSense.

Comment: knew that already, but thanks for the tip again. Others reading will find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, `int`, `float`, etc. are already lowercase. If you are wondering about `String`, there is a lowercase alias called `string`, so that doesn't need to be capitalized either. From your examples, most of the C# equivalent keywords are also already lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You must mean the intellisense feature used in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, the IDE should not try correct a case-sensitive language like C# (as mentioned in comments) but it appears that it actually does.

I just tried it and both VS2008 and VS2010 will correct the casing of keywords, such as foreach and public.

- Type `FOREACH` and press space, you get `foreach`
- Type `PUBLIC` and press space, you get `public`

I'm using default settings.

This is intellisense though, so if you type `IF` you get `IFormatProvider`